# Create Metafield for product in shopify rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, shopify

I am new to shopify application development and working on to create app which add time block on product page.

I have created rails app with form on home#index page as below

```
<%= form_tag('/home/save_product_options', id: "form_#{product.id}", 'data-shopify-app-submit' => 'unicorn_form_submit') do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :key %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :product_id, product.id %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :value %>
  <%= check_box_tag :product_timer, false, false, onclick: "add_key_value('#{product.id}')" %> Add timer to product <br>
  <%= submit_tag 'Save', disabled: true %>
<% end %>
```

So when admin select checkbox and submit, a metafield should be created for above product.

But it always return error 500 on form submit even though save_product_options path exists in application

Please suggest any direction

Comment: Can you check your rails server log and mention the error you're getting?

Comment: Actually i have deployed application in heroku and added heroku details in app settings of url and callback url. So it is only saying something went wrong. I mean it is not showing any details in heroku log also.

Comment: You can check your logs in heroku. `heroku logs` in your terminal

Comment: `2016-06-11T06:53:10.439694+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/home/save_product_options?hmac={hmac_code}&shop={shop}.myshopify.com&protocol=https://&authenticity_token={auth_token}" host={heroku_host_name} request_id={request_id} fwd="180.211.108.182" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=301ms status=500 bytes=1754`

Comment: Hey, its not clear, can you post more information by editing your question.

Comment: That is all I am getting, and that is why i am not able to trace it. Not getting any other details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114418/discussion-between-jeet-and-kumar-abinash).